# SyntaxError: Unexpected token in OpenCart site

Tags: javascript, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I wanted a spinner every time we click a link in a OpenCart software. So I used these code:

```
<style> 
  .se-pre-con {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url(img/loader.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
}

</style>

<div class="se-pre-con"></div>

<script>
//paste this code under head tag or in a seperate js file.
  // Wait for window load
  $(window).load(function() {
    // Animate loader off screen
    $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
  });
</script>
```

This code will load a spinner(loader.gif) everytime a page loads.

So I went to index.php page and modified the file like below

```
<?php
// Version
define('VERSION', '1.5.6.4');

// Configuration
if (file_exists('config.php')) {
    require_once('config.php');
}  

// Install 
if (!defined('DIR_APPLICATION')) {
    header('Location: install/index.php');
    exit;
}

// Startup
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php');

// Application Classes
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/customer.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/affiliate.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/currency.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/tax.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/weight.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/length.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/cart.php');

// Registry
$registry = new Registry();

// Loader
$loader = new Loader($registry);
$registry->set('load', $loader);

// Config
$config = new Config();
$registry->set('config', $config);

// Database 
$db = new DB(DB_DRIVER, DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$registry->set('db', $db);


?>

<style> 
  .se-pre-con {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url(img/loader.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
}

</style>

<div class="se-pre-con"></div>

<?php
// Store
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && (($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == '1'))) {
    $store_query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "store WHERE REPLACE(`ssl`, 'www.', '') = '" . $db->escape('https://' . str_replace('www.', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/.\\') . '/') . "'");
} else {
    $store_query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "store WHERE REPLACE(`url`, 'www.', '') = '" . $db->escape('http://' . str_replace('www.', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) . rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/.\\') . '/') . "'");
}

if ($store_query->num_rows) {
    $config->set('config_store_id', $store_query->row['store_id']);
} else {
    $config->set('config_store_id', 0);
}

// Settings
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "setting WHERE store_id = '0' OR store_id = '" . (int)$config->get('config_store_id') . "' ORDER BY store_id ASC");

foreach ($query->rows as $setting) {
    if (!$setting['serialized']) {
        $config->set($setting['key'], $setting['value']);
    } else {
        $config->set($setting['key'], unserialize($setting['value']));
    }
}

if (!$store_query->num_rows) {
    $config->set('config_url', HTTP_SERVER);
    $config->set('config_ssl', HTTPS_SERVER);   
}

// Url
$url = new Url($config->get('config_url'), $config->get('config_secure') ? $config->get('config_ssl') : $config->get('config_url'));    
$registry->set('url', $url);

// Log 
$log = new Log($config->get('config_error_filename'));
$registry->set('log', $log);

function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    global $log, $config;

    switch ($errno) {
        case E_NOTICE:
        case E_USER_NOTICE:
            $error = 'Notice';
            break;
        case E_WARNING:
        case E_USER_WARNING:
            $error = 'Warning';
            break;
        case E_ERROR:
        case E_USER_ERROR:
            $error = 'Fatal Error';
            break;
        default:
            $error = 'Unknown';
            break;
    }

    if ($config->get('config_error_display')) {
        echo '<b>' . $error . '</b>: ' . $errstr . ' in <b>' . $errfile . '</b> on line <b>' . $errline . '</b>';
    }

    if ($config->get('config_error_log')) {
        $log->write('PHP ' . $error . ':  ' . $errstr . ' in ' . $errfile . ' on line ' . $errline);
    }

    return true;
}

// Error Handler
set_error_handler('error_handler');

// Request
$request = new Request();
$registry->set('request', $request);

// Response
$response = new Response();
$response->addHeader('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$response->setCompression($config->get('config_compression'));
$registry->set('response', $response); 

// Cache
$cache = new Cache();
$registry->set('cache', $cache); 

// Session
$session = new Session();
$registry->set('session', $session);

// Language Detection
$languages = array();

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "language` WHERE status = '1'"); 

foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
    $languages[$result['code']] = $result;
}

$detect = '';

if (isset($request->server['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) && $request->server['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) { 
    $browser_languages = explode(',', $request->server['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);

    foreach ($browser_languages as $browser_language) {
        foreach ($languages as $key => $value) {
            if ($value['status']) {
                $locale = explode(',', $value['locale']);

                if (in_array($browser_language, $locale)) {
                    $detect = $key;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

if (isset($session->data['language']) && array_key_exists($session->data['language'], $languages) && $languages[$session->data['language']]['status']) {
    $code = $session->data['language'];
} elseif (isset($request->cookie['language']) && array_key_exists($request->cookie['language'], $languages) && $languages[$request->cookie['language']]['status']) {
    $code = $request->cookie['language'];
} elseif ($detect) {
    $code = $detect;
} else {
    $code = $config->get('config_language');
}

if (!isset($session->data['language']) || $session->data['language'] != $code) {
    $session->data['language'] = $code;
}

if (!isset($request->cookie['language']) || $request->cookie['language'] != $code) {      
    setcookie('language', $code, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30, '/', $request->server['HTTP_HOST']);
}           

$config->set('config_language_id', $languages[$code]['language_id']);
$config->set('config_language', $languages[$code]['code']);

// Language 
$language = new Language($languages[$code]['directory']);
$language->load($languages[$code]['filename']); 
$registry->set('language', $language); 

// Document
$registry->set('document', new Document());         

// Customer
$registry->set('customer', new Customer($registry));

// Affiliate
$registry->set('affiliate', new Affiliate($registry));

if (isset($request->get['tracking'])) {
    setcookie('tracking', $request->get['tracking'], time() + 3600 * 24 * 1000, '/');
}

// Currency
$registry->set('currency', new Currency($registry));

// Tax
$registry->set('tax', new Tax($registry));

// Weight
$registry->set('weight', new Weight($registry));

// Length
$registry->set('length', new Length($registry));

// Cart
$registry->set('cart', new Cart($registry));

//OpenBay Pro
$registry->set('openbay', new Openbay($registry));

// Encryption
$registry->set('encryption', new Encryption($config->get('config_encryption')));

// Front Controller 
$controller = new Front($registry);

// Maintenance Mode
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/maintenance'));

// SEO URL's
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/seo_url'));    

// Router
if (isset($request->get['route'])) {
    $action = new Action($request->get['route']);
} else {
    $action = new Action('common/home');
}

// Dispatch
$controller->dispatch($action, new Action('error/not_found'));

// Output
$response->output();
?>
<script>
//paste this code under head tag or in a seperate js file.
  // Wait for window load
  $(window).load(function() {
    // Animate loader off screen
    $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
  });
</script>
```

The page does load the spinner but when I click login or register I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
OK
<style> 
  .se-pre-con {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url(img/loader.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
}

</style>

<div class="se-pre-con"></div>

{"country_id":"223","name":"United States","iso_code_2":"US","iso_code_3":"USA","address_format":"{firstname} {lastname}\r\n{company}\r\n{address_1}\r\n{address_2}\r\n{city}, {zone} {postcode}\r\n{country}","postcode_required":"0","zone":[{"zone_id":"3613","country_id":"223","name":"Alabama","code":"AL","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"3614","country_id":"223","name":"Alaska","code":"AK","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"3615","country_id":"223","name":"American Samoa","code":"AS","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"3616","country_id":"223","name":"Arizona","code":"AZ","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"3617","country_id":"223","name":"Arkansas","code":"AR","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"3618","country_id":"223","name":"Armed Forces Africa","code":"AF","status":"1"},{"zone_id":"3619","country_id":"223","name":"Armed…
```

Please help how to fix it

Thank You

Comment: You forget to put quotes in `url(img/loader.gif)`. Replace it by `url("img/loader.gif")`

Comment: Maybe this is caused by the two **  at **<style>  Try to remove the **

Comment: @Sapikelio It did not fix. I tried both ways.

Comment: @shock_gone_wild ** was kept to make it bold in Stackover flow. I will correct it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first don't modify index file (You may lose file on update plus it's a bad practice)

Just modify `header.tpl` of your template file put your script.

```
// catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl:39
     <style>
        .se-pre-con {
          position: fixed;
          left: 0px;
          top: 0px;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          z-index: 9999;
          background: url('catalog/view/theme/default/image/loading.gif') center no-repeat #fff;
        }
      </style>

<script>
    //paste this code under head tag or in a seperate js file.
    // Wait for window load
    $(window).load(function() {
      // Animate loader off screen
      $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
    });
  </script>
```

Now In `header.tpl` after body `<div class="se-pre-con"></div>`

PS: Good practice is use your style file for stylesheet, script file for your js and `.tpl` file for html.